# nginx/FastCGI vs Apache/suPHP on Joomla sites

Tags: php, apache, joomla, nginx, webserver

I always used Apache and suPHP on my VPS. Now, since the page loading is not very fast, my hosting customer support suggested me to install nginx with FastCGI. I'm not sure of this, because nginx is installed on about 11% of servers, instead Apache is the most widely used webserver.

My questions so are:

- Is this system robust and stable? Do have it modules that cover every needs?
- Is nginx compatible with apache? For example I've seen that .htaccess file have to be rewritten...
- should I have problems with my sites in joomla? Maybe there should be modules, components or others that are not compatible with nginx?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes - it's stable and it has much much better performance than Apache (if configured properly of course)
2. No, nginx is not compatible with apache - configuration is completely different
3. Joomla is executed by PHP parser, so if you will run same PHP version as on your previous configuration, you shouldn't experience any problems.

Comment: Regarding compatibility: this means also that url rewriting through .htaccess file needs to be rewritten in nginx?

Comment: Yes, but there are some pages which will help you (or even automatically convert) to rewrite your URL RewriteRules. Google should be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this system robust and stable? Do have it modules that cover every needs?

Answer: Yes, Nginx is very nice and stable with almost all the modules required

Is nginx compatible with apache? For example I've seen that .htaccess file have to be rewritten...

Answer: No it is not compatible, you need to rewrite all the rules in nginx configuration files. But I think it is not very difficult for joomla, you can get sample nginx conf file for joomla .htaccess very easily.

should I have problems with my sites in joomla? Maybe there should be modules, components or others that are not compatible with nginx?

Answer: for Joomla, what you need is, just proper configuration and site will be live.

**BUT**

I think your speed issue will not be resolved by Nginx :-( 

Nginx will perform almost equal with your Joomla, it works great with static content.
As per my personal experience, Joomla itself is a very big problem with big database and user-base.

I hope this helps